# Ubuntu one music showing 'unknown artist' and 'unknown album' for most songs

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, mp3, metadata

I successfully uploaded 23GB of music from my hard drive (after lots of waiting) to Ubuntu One except that only ~20 artists/albums are showing up correctly and the rest are 'unknown'.  They are (almost) all mp3 files and the correct info shows up when loaded into a media player, including Rhythmbox and Banshee.

Thus, this is not a problem with the files themselves (info also shows up correctly under properties->audio in Nautilus) but rather a problem with U1.  There seems to be other threads with this issue but no answers, except for the excuse: "Ubuntu One does not currently support m4a files" which is clearly not the issue.  This is of particular concern for streaming to my iPhone since all the music is disorganized, which really defeats the whole purpose of the app.

I should note that most song titles are correct (except may contain a song number in front of them) which from what I understand is due to the fact that generally the file name is the song name.  Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exactly the same here, 10 of 262 albums are recognized correctly. Upload finished a few hours ago. I will let you know whether the problem persists or not.

Comment: I'm having the problem as well.  Is there any work-around?

Answer (score 1):

The part of our system that scans the track data in music files is delayed as we have lots of files to scan. This may take some time. Please let us know if you still have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Over the holidays there was a problem with the scanning server. It has been fixed, and you should get the proper tags for yours songs within the next 24hs.

Sorry for the problems it caused you :(

Comment: There still only seems to be only proper tags for the same 20 artists.  Is there something I need to do to update the tags?  I'd rather not have to re-upload all of my music if possible.