# Ubuntu One and MP3 tags

Tags: ubuntu-one, mp3, metadata

I recently upload my songs on Ubuntu One. Some of them were not recognized so, I've edited the mp3 tags using the "easy tag" software. 
All the songs have been synchronized correctly. I've waited one day (because of the thread [Ubuntu one music showing 'unknown artist' and 'unknown album' for most songs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89602/ubuntu-one-music-showing-unknown-artist-and-unknown-album-for-most-songs)), 
and now all my songs are listed under "unknow artist/unknow album".

What should I do?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Over the holidays there was a problem with the scanning server. It has been fixed, and you should get the proper tags for yours songs within the next 24hs.

Sorry for the problems it caused you  :(

Answer (score 1):

As far as I' concerned, U1 doesn't get the metadata from the ID3-Tags but from the filenames. For me it works, since I changed the filename-scheme to "%artist - %album - %track - %title.%extension". Most mediaplayers, like banshee or clementine (my choice) should give you the possibility to change it conveniently.